# Travel within EU Schengen area with lost residence permit card abroad

Tags: customs-and-immigration, italy, czech-republic, lost-documents

A friend in Prague just contacted me asking the possibility of traveling back to Italy. He is Pakistani passport holder and lives in Italy on student residence permit. He was traveling in Prague where somebody has stolen his documents and credit cards and also the residence permit. He has already filed a theft report of residence permit and other documents with local police in Prague.

Now, he wants to travel back to Italy. He has a flight back to Italy tomorrow booked with Czech airlines. So, what do you guys suggest about traveling within Schengen area with lost residence permit?

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the OP here is **abroad** whereas the linked question mentions a EU resident losing their residence permit in their country of residency. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JoErNanO There is indeed clearly a difference in the question, but does it make the answer any different? I am not sure, I would actually still consider it is duplicate. Unless you suggest there is a different answer. BTW, if the question was about how to get a new residence permit (in Czechh Republic or Italy), it would become different and interesting.

Comment: @Vince That's not relevant, duplicate means it's the same *question*.

Comment: @Vince I see your point. The answer will probably be different since in this case the OP must deal with foreign authorities, or consulates. Whereas the OP of the linked duplicate can ask for a new document using emergency routes, or similar services. Having said this, I think the question of how to obtain a new permit is a valid one and I might indeed ask it, provided we don't reopen this one.

Comment: @Relaxed I think it's always the same debate, I agree with you "duplicate" refers to the question, but then what's displayed is "This question already has an answer here" which means it could be a different question with the same answer.

Comment: @JoErNanO The question, to me, is about travelling within Schengen with a lost residence permit, which is exactly what the other question asked - in the other question, the OP would also travel back with lost papers. I don't see the need to deal with a consulate. Anyway, given the number of votes, I suppose it will be reopened, we will see if answers are helpful.

Comment: @JoErNanO I remember your colleague having a similar issue. Maybe you could post his solution as an answer?

Comment: Don't be afraid of telling the truth :J . Show them the copy of your RP, filed police report, original passport when traveling.  Once you get back to italy, you can get a replacement one. If you have any further questions, call up the italian embassy in prague.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be to find a [car-share](https://www.blablacar.com), or a series of car-shares from Prague to Italy. All other options can result in a check by the police and unpleasant time spent proving his identity, especially considering the recent refugee situation.

- Officials at Prague Airport generally don't check one's residency card, but he might be subject to racial profiling
- Buses through Germany and Austria are sometimes checked
- Trains are often patrolled by policemen at border stations, with racial profiling coming into play once again
- Private cars, on the other hand, are very rarely checked and the police is mostly interested in the contents of the trunk rather than the identity of the passengers

Comment: Germany always does have a passport control (racial profiling) through its borders (buses, trains, air) so avoid going through germany.  May be train through Prague-Vienna-Venice will work or fly through milan.

Comment: Rumor has it that cars aren't checked as often as trains and buses.