Traveling with a soft copy of residency permit in EU
In Rome italy, my wallet gotten stolen. It had my residency permit, which is valid for another month. I went to the police, and I got the police complaint which clearly mentions that my permit is lost/stolen.
Now I have to fly to Prague tomorrow. Is there any way they will let me leave ? If someone has been through the same situation please let me know.

What is your citizenship? Do you have a valid passport from your home country? Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47034/travel-within-eu-schengen-area-with-lost-residence-permit-card-abroad?rq=1

There will not be anyone to keep you from leaving, as there are no passport controls between Rome and Prague, but you do not a valid travel document to travel.

@KristvanBesien For third-country nationals: a residency permit alone is not enough to travel, even within the Schengen Area. Third country nationals must have a passport for travel outside of their country of residence.
